# Unable to call Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm creating a matrix multiplication class for a neural network project, and when calling the class it returns the `TypeError: 'MatrixOperations' object is not subscriptable` error.

Here's the code:

```
class MatrixOperations:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def transpose(matx,self):
        transMatx = [[0 for i in range(len(matx))] for j in range(len(matx[0]))]
        for i in range(len(matx[0])):
            transMatx[i] = self.getColumn(matx, i)
        return(transMatx)

mo = MatrixOperations()
mat2 = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
mo.transpose(mat2)
```

Comment: In a class method , `self` should be the first parameter. `def transpose(self, matx):`

Comment: What do you think `matx`  is in your method? It is the instance. Why did you call the second argument `self`? The names of the arguments don't matter, it's their position, the second argument won't get passed the instance just because you named it `self`

Comment: Note: this could be made a static method. [Static methods in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/735975)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you wrote the definition for the `transpose` function incorrectly. In Python, class functions should always have a first argument of `self` if you want them to operate on instances of that class. In your case you put `self` second, so Python is trying to index into `matx`, which is your `MatrixOperations` object and since you have not overloaded the indexing operation, this throws an error. Fortunately, the solution is simple:

```
def transpose(self, matx):
    ...
```